# Compare directory structures

Tags: linux, unix, find, rsync

Is it possible to compare directory structures of two different server? I need to compare the directory structure of a test with that of a production server and list the directories that exists on prod but no in test (the test server has lot less info).
I am using following rsync command

```
rsync -rvnc --delete userid@servername:/directory /directory
```

Besides above rsync, i have also tried running find commands on both server, sdiff the two output of find

```
find directory1 -type d -printf "%P\n" | sort > file1

find directory2 -type d -printf "%P\n" | sort > file2

sdiff file 1 file2 > file3
```

Please help which approach would be better.

Comment: Rsync would be faster. What's not working about it?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `rsync -ai dir1/ dir2/ --dry-run` to create a machine-readable list of changes between dir1 and dir2.

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42160545/2536029